# Enable Submit Button Based On Class Names in Bootstrap using Javascript

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE**

I created a workaround this problem. I simply added `hide` to the password fields and then made the script show them once the email was valid. I then made it so once the passwords where valid, the Submit button was enabled. I will update me code below to reflect this solution

---

---

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

I am creating a form using Bootstrap framework. I have two scripts (one that checks the email and another that checks the passwords.)

**SEE THIS SCRIPT IN ACTION:** http://www.green-panda.com/adminarea/temp.php and then click Add New user. Note: I will delete this page once I have found a solution and posted it here.

**EMAIL SCRIPT**

```
                    <script>
                    function validateForm()
                    {
                    var x=document.forms["addUser"]["email"].value;
                    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
                    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
                    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
                      {
                      document.getElementById("emaildiv").className +=" error";
                      document.getElementById("passdiv1").className =" control-group hide";
                        document.getElementById("passdiv2").className =" control-group hide";
                      document.getElementById("emailhelp").innerHTML =" Must be a valid email address";
                      }
                     else{
                        document.getElementById("emaildiv").className =" control-group success";
                        document.getElementById("passdiv1").className =" control-group";
                        document.getElementById("passdiv2").className =" control-group";
                        document.getElementById("emailhelp").innerHTML =" Looks Good!";
                     }
                    }
                </script>
```

**Password Script**

```
                <script> 
                    function validatePwd() {
                        var invalid = " "; // Invalid character is a space
                        var minLength = 8; // Minimum length
                        var maxLength = 16; //Maximum Length
                        var pw1 = document.addUser.password.value;
                        var pw2 = document.addUser.password2.value;
                        // check for a value in both fields.
                        if (pw1 == '' || pw2 == '') 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("passdiv1").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passdiv2").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passhelp").innerHTML =" Type your password twice.";
                            return false;
                        }
                        // check for minimum length
                        if (document.addUser.password.value.length < minLength) 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("passdiv1").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passdiv2").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passhelp").innerHTML ="Your password must be 8-16 characters long.";
                            return false;
                        }
                        // check for maximum length
                        if (document.addUser.password.value.length > maxLength) 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("passdiv1").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passdiv2").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passhelp").innerHTML ="Your password must be 8-16 characters long.";
                            return false;
                        }
                        // check for spaces
                        if (document.addUser.password.value.indexOf(invalid) > -1) 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("passdiv1").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passdiv2").className +=" error";
                            document.getElementById("passhelp").innerHTML ="Sorry, spaces are not allowed.";
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                                if (pw1 != pw2) 
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("passdiv1").className +=" error";
                                    document.getElementById("passdiv2").className +=" error";
                                    document.getElementById("passhelp").innerHTML ="Passwords must match.";
                                    return false;
                                }
                        else {
                                document.getElementById("passdiv1").className =" control-group success";
                                document.getElementById("passdiv2").className =" control-group success";
                                document.getElementById("submit").className ="btn btn-primary";
                                document.getElementById("passhelp").innerHTML ="Looks Good!.";
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```

As you can see in the scripts, once the requirements are met, the classes in both cases are changed to "control-group success" By default my submit button has a class of "disabled" causing the button to not be clickable. I have attempted to create a script that checks the class name of both the `emaildiv` and the `passdiv2` automatically and changes the button class from `btn btn-primary disabled` to `btn btn-primary` once both classes are set to success.

**This is what I have so far and does not work at all**

**IN THE UPDATED SOLUTION AT THE TOP, I AM NO LONGER USING THE SCRIPT BELOW.**

```
<script> 
function submit() {
    var x = document.getElementById("emaildiv").className;
    var y = document.getElementById("passdiv2").className;
    if (x == "control-group success" || y == "control-group success")
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").className ="btn btn-primary";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").className ="btn btn-primary disabled";
    }
}
</script>
```

I have been trying to make this work since before lunch and now i have returned with yet no success. Please help in any way you possibly can! Thank you!

**UPDATE:** Is it because there is nothing calling `function submit()` ? If so how would I make it to automatically do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains syntax error.
You have to quote the id of submit.

```
function submit() {
    var x = document.getElementById("emaildiv").className;
    var y = document.getElementById("passdiv2").className;
    if (x == "control-group success" || y == "control-group success")
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").className ="btn btn-primary";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").className ="btn btn-primary disabled";
    }
}
```

I haven't tested though, It would be awesome if you provide simple jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net with all your code ?

Comment: Well it has to have all the bootstrap scripts and css linked to it to work. But I can give a link to the program: http://www.green-panda.com/adminarea/temp.php and then click `add new user` button it should bring the form up.

Comment: You don't even need to disable the button. Please use this article to learn about basic form validation http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm

Comment: For the purpose of the site, I need to disable the submit button. I understand you can do this, But I need to disable it and then re-enable it one the two requirements are met.

Comment: Then you can apply onchange event handler to input field and and run submit function.

Comment: Your code looks like a complete mess. Can you please provide a easy to use jsfiddle. Also Please Don't downvote because problem is in your logic of validation and code.

Comment: I don't appreciate that, I'm not looking for coding that is all neat and in one line. It's written as I can understand it.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/gZg7w/ but like I said before, you will not be able to do much with it as nothing with bootstrap framework is there.

Comment: It's 2am morning at my place so I will take a look tomorrow.